# Theme problem in dynamic features of android

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic-feature-module

First of all, I apologize for my weak english language skill.
I have a problem with my project.
My project uses dynamic features and has 4 modules (app,A,B,C) and my application is single activity,it means main activity is in module app and module A,B,C just contain fragments.I want module A has its theme separately and all of drawable in its res directory separately. I create themes.xml in module A res directory and define a theme that its parent is the theme of the app module.

```
<style name="ThemeOfA" parent="AppTheme">
```

now i set some attr's value in this theme like :

```
<item name="mainAModuleBackground">@@drawable/background_a</item>
```

and i use that attr in some layout that are in module A.But when i run application,it crashes and the log is can not inflate that layout which uses "mainAModuleBackground" attr.
I know that this is because I don't setTheme correctly in module A
I tried set theme in manifest of module A.
I tried set theme in onCreate of fragment which is in module A,but the problem i still here.
Do you have any idea what should i do?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, in my case it doesn't even compile. Have you solved this somehow?

Comment: unfortunately not yet :(